# number of linear maps from $V\to V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Question is to find total number of linear maps from vector space $\mathbb R^3(\mathbb R)$ to vector space $\mathbb R (\mathbb R)$ which are not Onto?

I think trivial map, $T (x, y,z)=0$ could be one of them. But book says infinite?

Related to above question I know how many total number of linear transformation are there from a finite dim vector space to another finite dim vector space over finite field. But what can we say if field is infinite?

Comment: What's $R^3(R)$ and $R(R)$?

Comment: Is it possible to represent the maps in some way, like matrices?

Comment: $R^3$(R) is vector space of 3 tuples over field R real numbers. And R (R) is vector space of real numbers over real numbers

Comment: @neptun are u giving hint. Or asking?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, because it is unusual notation. @singularity

Comment: All nonzero linear map from $\mathbb R^3(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R(\mathbb R)$ is onto. So you are right. (But I think you need to change your title: That is not actually what you are asking for).

Comment: @singularity So, you're looking for all non-surjective linear maps $\phi:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$, in other words.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski yes

Comment: John's comment is correct. The only such map is the zero map.

Comment: @John so not onto are 1. And onto are infinite.right? What about reverse R $\to R^3$ whts their number